# Jetty-ssl.xml password hiding

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ssl, jetty, jetty-8

I was configuring my Jetty ssl using this [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL). I was configuring it for my tomcat keystore and tomcat trust-store so that instead of jetty default certificates, my tomcat certificates are used for ssl connections. While configuring i found we need to mention the keystore and trust-store passphrase. But i guess this might expose my tomcat keystore and trust-store passphrase if somehow jetty get exposed. 
So can anyone suggest anyother method ?

I thought of passing the passphrase file path to the jetty-ssl.xml, so that i am not exposing my passphrase. But didn't found any similar functionality of jetty. They only provided the method to obfuscating the password [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Secure_Passwords).

Comment: What version of Jetty?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention the version of jetty. Its **Jetty v8.1.11**

Answer (score 0):

Jetty uses the SSL defaults in Java.

Namely the `java.security`, `javax.net.ssl` provided packages.

[`KeyStore.load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#load%28java.io.InputStream,%20char%5B%5D%29) requires a password if the keystore itself has one.  Otherwise that `KeyStore` cannot be loaded for use in SSL.

Those `KeyStore` instances are then passed into the `javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory` or `javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory`.  Without those, you have a fairly useless SSL configuration.

In short, if the stores on disk have a password, then you have to tell Jetty those passwords, either in obfuscated form, or plain text.

Comment: i agree Joakim Erdfelt, but is there any mechanism provided by jetty where i can mention the path of my file containing the **passphrase** instead of passing passphrase in obfuscated form or plain text?